# JQuery AJAX call to php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to replace page reloading PHP scripts in a web page with AJAX calls.

I am using JQuery to run the AJAX scripts but it doesn't seem to be doing anything so I attempted to write an incredibly basic script just to test it.

My directory is as follows

```
public_html/index.php
           /scripts/phpfunctions.php
                   /jqueryfunctions.js
```

index.php contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- jquery functions -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqueryfunctions.js"></script>

    <!-- php functions -->
    <?php include 'scripts/phpfunctions.php' ?>

</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="testButt">TEST</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the `phpfunctions.php` page which I am trying to call contains just an echo if an argument is set

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["action"])) {
        echo "test has been run";
    }

?>
```

The `jqueryfunctions.js` script I am trying to run is

```
$(document).read(function () {
    $('#testButt').on('click', function () {
        console.log("jquery call worked"); // this bit does run when button is clicked
        $.ajax({ // this bit doesn't seem to do anything
            url: 'scripts/phpfunctions.php?action=run_test',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ajaxdata').html(data);
            },
            error: function (log) {
                console.log(log.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I see that the jqueryfunctions.js function is being called by the first console.log but it doesn't seem to be calling my phpfunctions.php function.

I was expecting to see the php echo "test has been run" but this doesn't happen.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just pointing out, you have missed the closing `>` off the end body tag, this could be an issue

Comment: As pointed out by @Jai you don't have a `<div id="ajaxdata">` in your body. So the AJAX call is probably running, and successful, but it is trying to display the data in an element that does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `isset()` method:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["action"])) {
       if($_GET["action"] == "run_test") {
          echo "test has been run";
       }
    }
?>
```

and if you are using ajax then why do you need to include it on index page:

```
<?php include 'scripts/phpfunctions.php' ?>
```

and i can't find this element `$('#ajaxdata')` on your index page.

---

Also you can check the network tab of your inspector tool to see the xhr request to the `phpfunctions.php` and see if this gets successfull or there is any error.

Comment: I didn't realize the success function was trying to place it into an existing element. Is it possible to store the result in a variable instead of populating an element?

Comment: @Trent yes you can have a global variable and that can be used to store it but thing to remember you should have to use promises then.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is here:

```
$(document).read(function() {

    $('#testButt').on('click', function() {

        console.log("jquery call worked"); // this bit does run when button is clicked

        $.ajax({   // this bit doesn't seem to do anything
            url: 'scripts/phpfunctions.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {action:'run_test'}, // <------ Here
            success: function(data) {
                $('#ajaxdata').html(data);
            },
            error: function(log) {
                console.log(log.message);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

[jQuery says](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting.

So you should set `data: {key:'value'}`

Comment: Not quite. You can use both notation. You can give directly a query string or an object that jQuery will convert to a query string, so "var1=1&var2=2" work like {var1: 1, var2: 2}. Both are ok

Comment: I am a bit disputed on whether to use this method to pass an argument or the one @sam swift suggested (passing it in the URL)

Answer (score 1):

Most things look fine, but your `data` attribute is designed for "POST" requests, try to add the data to the url as follows:

```
$( document ).read( function ()
{
    $( '#testButt' ).on( 'click', function ()
    {
        console.log( "jquery call worked" ); // this bit does run when button is clicked
        $.ajax( {   // this bit doesn't seem to do anything
            url: 'scripts/phpfunctions.php?action=run_test', // Add the GET request to the end of the URL
            type: 'GET',
            //data: 'action=run_test', Unrequired noise :P (this is for post requests...)
            success: function ( data )
            {
                $( '#ajaxdata' ).html( data );
            },
            error: function ( log )
            {
                console.log( log.message );
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

And also (*as mentioned in my comments*), you need to finish your bodys closing tag:

```
</body> <!-- Add the closing > in :P -->

</html>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: _Unrequired noise :P (this is for post requests...)_ are you sure?

Comment: that is automatically done by jquery ajax if req is get then it sends data in the url and if is post then it won't be send in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you load ajaxfunctions.js? It look like in your code you never load the resource
And change

```
<button id="xxx">
```

In

```
<button type="button" id="xxx">
```

So the page isn't reloaded

Comment: that is not in the form so reload doesn't happens.

Comment: Oh, yes, thus the problem must be that ajaxfunctions.js is never loaded in the page

Comment: I've used AJAX many a time without `type="button"`, IMO, this isn;t needed

Comment: Sure, if it isn't in a form you're completely right, my mistake